# Emacs shell command not found

Tags: shell, emacs

I work on Mac OS X 10.5.8. I am trying to learn emacs. I am very new to it and today tried to enter shell commands from within emacs. I entered `pdflatex filename`. However, it gives me an error saying

```
/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found
```

I have LaTeX installed and pdflatex works fine from the command line in the terminal.

I get a similar error for a command `lsd` that I have defined in my `.bash_profile` file. This works fine too on the command line in the terminal.

The command `ls` works fine in the emacs shell.

Does anyone have an idea what might be happening.

How I can get emacs to recognize all the commands that work fine on the command line in the terminal.
Is there anyway I can make the environment used by emacs shell and terminal command line identical?
If so, is there any reason you would recommend against doing so? I know very little of both bash and emacs.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that the Emacs shell is working in a different environment from the one you have at the terminal command line. Compare the output of `env` when run inside the Emacs shell and when run in the terminal.  Pay particular attention to the values of `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct; the Emacs shell is has a different environment. I changed the PATH of the emacs shell using `M-x setenv`. With that pdflatex works in emacs shell. However, the command `lsd` that I defined in .bash_profile does not work. Is there any way I can make the environment identical.

Comment: .bash_profile is loaded for your login shell only. If you want to customize regular shells (such as xterm windows, or Emacs shells), you need to put the customization in .bashrc instead. Many people will source .bashrc from .bash_profile, so that you get all of your customizations in your login shell, but only those in .bashrc in your regular shells.

Comment: @Tyler - Thanks for your reply. I opened my .bash_profile file and saved it as a .bashrc file. The `lsd` command, however, still does not work.

Comment: Strange. .bashrc gets loaded for me automatically every time I launch an emacs shell. Maybe try some debugging lines - in .bashrc, add: echo "bashrc loaded", in .bash_profile, add: echo "bashprofile loaded", then in emacs call a new shell: M-x shell. If you see one or both of the echo lines you'll know what emacs is reading each time you open a new shell.

Comment: If you are using `M-x shell`, then you can provide emacs-specific initialisation for SHELLNAME (e.g. "bash") in `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` or `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh` (See `C-h f shell`). Some alternatives to `M-x shell` are `M-x term` (or `M-x ansi-term`) and `M-x eshell`.

Comment: @Tyler - Thanks again. I put the echo command and `M-x shell` does load `.bashrc`. The `lsd` command I have defined in my .bashrc also works fine in `M-x shell`. However, the commands do not work when the shell command is entered using `M-!` in emacs. Thanks!

Comment: The Emacs shell command (M-!) is not interactive by default so bash will not load your .bashrc.  You can change this by adding `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` to your .emacs init file.  The -i tells bash to be interactive, which makes it load the ~/.bashrc file.  That's the easy work-around but there maybe things in your ~/.bashrc that you don't necessarily want when running a quick shell command.  In that case, it may be better practice to set the BASH_ENV environment variable so that you have finer control of what happens.

Answer (score 1):

From help for `shell` command:

> Program used comes from variable ‘explicit-shell-file-name’,
>    or (if that is nil) from the ESHELL environment variable,
>    or (if that is nil) from ‘shell-file-name’.
>   If a file ‘~/.emacs_SHELLNAME’ exists, or ‘~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh’,
>   it is given as initial input (but this may be lost, due to a timing
>   error, if the shell discards input when it starts up).
>   The buffer is put in Shell mode, giving commands for sending input
>   and controlling the subjobs of the shell.  See ‘shell-mode’.
>   See also the variable ‘shell-prompt-pattern’.

So you can just create symlink `~/.emacs_bash` (for bash) or `~/.emacs_zsh` (for zsh). Alternatively set variable `explicit-shell-file-name` to point to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` whichever you use or you can play which `ESHELL` environment variable as well.

Comment: On my spacemacs (on macOS), I needed to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for a bash shell. As Adam mentioned, I created ~/.emacs_bash file and added "export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk". It works!

Answer (score 0):

According to the following [article](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html). If you launch emacs from a shell, it will inherit the shell's environment variables. Therefore, just launch emacs from whatever shell you are most comfortable with to automatically set the environment variables. For example:

```
cd /file_path
emacs file_name
```