# How to run cargo from Emacs

Tags: emacs, rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing tests in Rust with Emacs. Is it possible to run the `cargo run` command of my test file in Emacs itself, rather than switching to the terminal for every build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `Cargo.toml` file (or the project root directory), run `M-x compile` and then enter `cargo run` and then hit `RET`.  From that same directory you can run `M-x recompile`.

You could bind the above to short key bindings, but you should probably investigate [cargo.el](https://github.com/kwrooijen/cargo.el).

Comment: Thanks. That almost worked. I had to add this to my .init.el file: `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` to make bash load my .bashrc file. I found that here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393628/emacs-shell-command-not-found#4393645)

Answer (score 0):

[rustic](https://github.com/brotzeit/rustic) mode provides an interface to a number of cargo commands. Among other things you can build, lint, and run tests at point. In the guide [Configuring Emacs for Rust development](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/#rustic) I'm describing setup and usage in detail.